# May a random access iterator to end be incremented by zero?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

The title says it all really. Given an iterator to end, may it be incremented by zero without invoking undefined behavior?

Case in point - does the following code work to return an iterator to the specified index - or to `end` if the index is out of range?

```
std::vector<Type>::iterator Class::fromIndex(size_t index) {
    return member_vector.begin() + std::min(index, member_vector.size());
}
```

If the behavior for `std::advance` or `std::next` are different that would be interesting to know as well, but here I am interested specifically in `operator+`.

Comment: It will be extremely strange if incrementing by zero leads to UB, although I'm curious to see the answer.

Comment: An excellent question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's a well-defined no-op**, say I.

> Given an iterator to end, may it be incremented by zero without invoking undefined behavior? *[..]* I am interested specifically in operator`+`.

For random access iterators, table 115 under `[random.access.iterators]` tells us (under *"Operational Semantics"*, and after "expanding" the meaning of the `while` loop there given) that `(r += 0) ≡ r`, so `(.end() += 0) ≡ .end()`.

The definition for `r + 0` is given in terms of that.

> If the behavior for `std::advance` or `std::next` are different that would be interesting to know as well.

For everything else, `std::next` is defined in terms of `std::advance`, which in `[iterator.operations]` doesn't explicitly say that this is well-defined but it seems pretty obvious from the wording, which defers to the English-language definition for "increment"/"decrement": *"Increments (or decrements for negative `n`) iterator reference `i` by `n`".*

We know that the English-language "increment"/"decrement" by zero is a no-op in all practical terms.